# How to print only two digits of the elements in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

Matlab often displays matrices where the elements have a lot of digits. However, I'd like to print only 2 digits (with rounding where needed). For example: the matrix

```
1         0.932482
4.209402  0
```

should be printed as

```
1.00  0.93
4.21  0
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
format short

a = [3.14 0; .45987 1.255]

a = 
      3.1400         0
      0.4599    1.2550

format bank

a = 
      3.14             0
      0.46          1.25
```

I don't know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) to affect the way Matlab display **data**.

Alternatively you can use fprintf statements with a [format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0hr54) string of your choosing.